# What is the purpose of using the -i and -1 in the following: array[name.Length - i] = name[i - 1];

Tags: c#, arrays

array[name.Length - i] = name[i - 1];

In the piece of code above, I understand that the purpose of it is is taking each letter of the name array and placing it into the array named array. What I am not sure about is the logical explanation as to what exactly the -i and the -1 is doing. Is this just syntax I have to memorize?

Thus far, I understand that the left side of the assignment state is indicating where the letters are going ( 1 letter a at time) while the right side is indicating where the letters are coming from (1 letter at a time). However, the reason for the structure is still not clear to me.

The purpose of the code is to ask the user to enter their name. Use an array to reverse the name and then store the result in a new string. 
        /// Display the reversed name on the console.

```
    {
        Console.Write("What's your name? ");
        var name = Console.ReadLine();

        var array = new char[name.Length];
        for (var i = name.Length; i > 0; i--)
            array[name.Length - i] = name[i - 1];

        var reversed = new string(array);
        Console.WriteLine("Reversed name: " + reversed);
    }
```

Comment: It's just a backwards loop that adds to an array at position `name.Length - i` (so, starting from `0` onwards) the char from the `name` string (here, treated as a char array), starting from `name[i - 1]` (from `string.Length -1` backwards), thus from the end of it, reversing the order of the string's chars.

Comment: Many such things are made crystal clear when you step through code using the **[awesome, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**.  It will also make you a better coder because you understand better how the code works.

Comment: These are all good explanations on this thread. What you have to remember is that in c# arrays are zero based. Therefore, "Lily" would be initialized as an array with 4 indexes. However, name[4] throws an exception. Instead, name[0] would equal 'L' and name[3] would equal 'y'.

Comment: __Numbering/Indexing__ is zero-based but the __Count and Length__  are regular numbers. So "Pete" has a Length of `4` but those 4 characters are numbered from 0 to 3.

Answer (score 3):

Just count and see what the value of `i` is in each loop iteration.
Let's imagine name.Length is 10.
Then, in the first iteration, `i` = 10, so
`array[name.Length - i] = name[i - 1];` means
`array[10 - 10] = name[10 - 1]; or: array[0] = name[9]`
Next iteration: `array[10 - 9] = name[9 - 1] or: array[1] = name[8]`
Next iteration: `array[10 - 8] = name[8 - 1] or: array[2] = name[7]`
etc
See how this works?

> Is this just syntax I have to memorize?

No, you just need to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `i` is going to be a number, so `i - 1` literally means 'a number minus one'.

It might be helpful to actually look through the loop manually. You name is 'Lily', so the `for` statement will be:

```
for (var i = name.Length; i > 0; i--)
```

or

```
for (var i = "Lily".Length (or '4'); while i is greater than zero; decrement i by 1 on each loop)
```

so the first time through would be something like:

```
array[name.Length - i] = name[i - 1];
```

or

```
array[4 - 4] = name[4 - 1]
```

or

```
array[0] = name[3] // and remember that arrays are zero-index, so name[3] will be the last letter "y"
```

and the next time through will be:

```
array[4 - 3] = name[3 - 1]
```

or

```
array[1] = name[2]
```

etc